# How can I get rid of parentheses around int in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to get rid of parentheses that surround an integer so that I can pass it to int_of_string

For example, I'd like to pass (-1) to int_of_string and but I don't know how to get rid of the parentheses first so that -1 can be returned.

I'm a beginner at OCaml so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you mean in the source text, or in a string-valued variable?

Comment: a string-valued variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that returns the substring between the rightmost `'('` and the leftmost `')'`:

```
let inside_parens s =
    let lpar = 
        try String.rindex s '('
        with Not_found -> -1
    in
    let rpar =
        try String.index s ')'
        with Not_found -> String.length s
    in
    String.sub s (lpar + 1) (rpar - lpar - 1)
```

It works for the example you give:

```
# int_of_string (inside_parens "(-1)");;
- : int = -1
```

You might need to adjust the code if you want to handle some cases that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scanf.sscanf` to parse the string and extract the integer component:

```ml
(* inside_parens "(-1)" returns -1 *)
let inside_parens s = Scanf.sscanf s "(%d)" Fun.id
```